# Shell script printf not printing variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm new in stackoverflow, I’m trying to print something like that.

```
From: email@domain.com
To: rcpt@domain.com
Date: date
LOG_ID: ID
```

I’m reading the Postfix logs, which contains the following text:

```
Oct 28 10:42:48 host postfix/pickup[8779]: 4B0782A016E: uid=1000 from=<from@from.com>
Oct 28 10:42:48 host postfix/cleanup[14607]: 4B0782A016E: message-id=<20211028134248.4B0782A016E@mail.democloud.com>
Oct 28 10:42:48 host postfix/qmgr[2656]: 4B0782A016E: from=<from@from.com>, size=400, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 28 10:42:50 host postfix/smtp[14610]: 4B0782A016E: to=<rcpt@rcpt.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.192.26]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0/0/1.1/0.64, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1635428569 jl7si2828702qvb.144 - gsmtp)
Oct 28 10:42:50 host postfix/qmgr[2656]: 4B0782A016E: removed
```

To perform the task I created the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
    echo "
    Ingresar cuenta de correo
    Ej.: $0 rcpt@rcpt.com

"
    exit 1
fi

RCPT="$1"

MAILOG="/var/log/mail.log"
STATS_DIR="/tmp"

echo -e "\n==== Detalle Total de Envios a <$1> ==== "
echo

QUEUEID=`grep -w "to=<${RCPT}>" ${MAILOG} | grep -E "status=(sent|deferred|bounced)" | awk -F"smtp" '{print $2}' | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e s'/ //'g | sort | uniq`
for QID in ${QUEUEID} ; do
EMAIL=`grep ${QID} /var/log/mail.log | sed -r 's/^([^;]*;)[^;]*;/\1/' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {print $7}' | grep -w "from=" | tr -d , | grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b"`
RCPT=`grep ${QID} /var/log/mail.log | sed -r 's/^([^;]*;)[^;]*;/\1/' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {print $7}' | grep -w "to=" | tr -d , | grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b"`
DATE=`grep ${QID} /var/log/mail.log | sed -r 's/^([^;]*;)[^;]*;/\1/' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {print $1, $2,$3}'`

printf "From: $s\nDestinatario: $s\nFecha: $s\nLOG_ID: $s\n\n" "${EMAIL}" "${RCPT}" "${DATE}" "${QID}"

done

exit 0
```

My problem is running printf, the script output is empty.

What’s the problem? Can you help me improve the script, thank you.

Regards,

Comment: primary issue is the `printf` format string ... you need to replace `$s` with `%s`, and to be honest, I'm glad to see I'm not the only person who (occasionally) makes this same typing mistake! :-)  ; 2nd issue ... `DATE` doesn't contain what you think it contains ... before the `printf` add `typeset -p DATE` to see the contents of `DATE`

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck and fix all mistakces.

Comment: Don't use uppercase variable names. Those are conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: from an 'improvement' perspective the 3x variables could probably be populated from a single `awk` script (that replaces all the `grep/sed/awk/tr/uniq/sort` stuff), eg, `read -r EMAIL RCPT DATE < <(awk -v qid="${QID}" ' ... awk code to find and print 3 values on single line of output ...')`